# Visual Studio Add-On and extensions performance monitoring?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, add-in

I'm using / testing a lot of extensions or add-on to Visual Studio.

As my Visual Studio is quite low, I'm wondering if some extensions are causing high CPU load.

Is there any way to monitor memory, disk and CPU usage **per extension** ? 
Google Chrome Task manager provides such functionality... Is there the same for Visual Studio ?

Answer (score 0):

DotTrack addon - visual studio 
or
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools#.NET
.net performance analysis

Try this link : http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/ ^^

Comment: Not what he asked for.  Looking for a tool inside Visual Studio that shows resource usage per extension.

Answer (score 0):

This one is currently available for 2012, 2013, 2015

Extensions Monitor

https://www.visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8dc77c87-a36b-4b79-809c-0102911786db

[image]